# VS Code customize file explorer window color theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Does anyone know how to customize the file explorer window color theme in VS Code? Also how to customize the color of line numbers?

For example, when using the built-in High Contrast color theme, I can see that the file explorer and line number colors are different. But I can't find a way to customize the colors when using an extension color theme, like the material-theme.

Answer (score 33):

From your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sideBar.background": "#424d66",
    "list.hoverBackground": "#41a6d9",
}
```

File explorer uses [sidebar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_side-bar) and [list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_lists-and-trees) colors.

Color of line numbers:

```json
"editorLineNumber.foreground": "#41a6d9",
"editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#ff6a00",
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors

Comment: The explorer list is very compact IMO. Is there a way I can increase each item height?

Comment: Only if you zoom in the entire interface.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

assuming you'd like to get a white sidebar and black text in it you need to edit your settings.json like this:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"sideBar.background": "#ffffff",
"sideBar.foreground": "#000000",
"list.hoverForeground": "#ffffff" 
}
```

Comment: Hello from 2022! This is the correct answer, in my time.